# SharpDX Toolkit: Draw Text

Tags: c#, xna, directx, toolkit, sharpdx

I want to draw some text in my Toolkit Game with the following code:

```
SpriteFont spriteFont;
Vector2 pointStringPosition = new Vector2(5, 5);
int intPoints = 0;
//...
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
//...
spriteFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Schrift.xml");
//...
spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, intPoints.ToString(), pointStringPosition, Color.DarkOrange);
```

Schrift.xml is in the Content folder and constitutes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TkFont>
  <FontName>Arial</FontName>
  <Size>13</Size>
  <Spacing>0</Spacing>
  <LineSpacing>0</LineSpacing>
  <UseKerning>false</UseKerning>
  <Format>Auto</Format>
  <CharacterRegions>
    <CharacterRegion>
      <Start>32</Start>
      <End>127</End>
    </CharacterRegion>
  </CharacterRegions>
  <DefaultCharacter>32</DefaultCharacter>
  <Style>Regular</Style>
  <NoPremultiply>false</NoPremultiply>
</TkFont>
```

If the .csproj constitutes this:

```
<ToolkitFont Include="Content\Schrift.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</ToolkitFont>
```

It throw an AssetNotFoundException.

If the .csproj constitutes this:

```
<Content Include="Content\Schrift.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

It says:

> Registered ContentReader of type
>   [SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.SpriteFontContentReader] fails to load
>   content of type [SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics.SpriteFont] from file
>   [Schrift.xml].

If the .csproj constitutes this:

```
<ToolkitFont Include="Content\Schrift.xml">
      <Link>Content\Schrift.xml</Link>
</ToolkitFont>
```

I get an error, because the Link element doesn't work.

What is wrong? Or is there a better / easier oportunity to draw text with SharpDX?

Answer (score 1):

The SharpDX Toolkit doesn't use XNA file format but a [custom YAML format](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Toolkit/Common/SpriteFontApp/Content/Arial13.xml). Check the [samples](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples) and specifically the [SpriteFontApp](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Toolkit/Common/SpriteFontApp/SpriteFontAppGame.cs)

Comment: I have add and use this [xml file](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Toolkit/Common/SpriteFontApp/Content/Arial13.xml), but I get the same error.

Comment: You can't load the file directly. It needs to be processed at compile time by the "ToolkitFont" action on the spritefont (https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Toolkit/WindowsDesktop/SpriteFontApp/SpriteFontApp.Desktop.csproj#L76). See the samples.

Comment: Thanks for your many exsamples, but it does not work. What I have done see in the question (I have update it).

Comment: Have you really looked at SharpDX samples? None of the samples are loading with the xml extension `Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Schrift.xml");` but simply `Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Schrift");` https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Toolkit/Common/SpriteFontApp/SpriteFontAppGame.cs#L66

Comment: I know, everyone says without the formatend, but for me it works only with the ending. The Texture2D work like that, too (`text2SnakeBody = Content.Load<Texture2D>("snake.png");`).

Comment: It is not working if you are using a custom action like `ToolkitFont` or `ToolkitTexture`. And fonts requires this custom action, so you can't use `.xml`. You should use `ToolkitTexture` instead of making the Content copied to the output directory.

Comment: I don't realy understand how to create a custom action like 'ToolkitFont'. Where I can't use '.xml'?

Comment: The ToolkitFont action will show up if you have installed SharpDX Toolkit nuget packages, otherwise you will have to manually add a `build\SharpDX.targets`file from the binary distrib into your csproj. All SharpDX samples are based on nuget packages, so you should consider starting from there. You can also try to use the SharpDX Visual Studio extension http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f220534-d52e-4e16-a45b-c6086b3a3ae8 to setup a new project

Comment: I think than I will install SharpDX. But how can I download / install [this](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/)? Have I to install Nuget, or is there an easier way to download this directly? (I hate extra download apps)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was due to the fact that I had not put the Build Action to "TookitFont"

So in code **without .xml extension**

and in the file properties:

- Build Action: ToolkitFont
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy if newer

Or in the .csproj file:

```
<ToolkitFont Include="Content\Arial16.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</ToolkitFont>
```